# I modified my registry and now my laptop doesn't report its battery or power settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery, power

I saved a backup of my registry and then made a change to it.

After the change, the Windows 7 battery meter no longer reported how much battery power was left.

I also was no longer able to change between Power Profiles in the Control Panel.

I tried to restore the original registry but it didn't restore the lost power features.

Now I have to keep my laptop plugged in all day because I never know how much power I have left.

Anyone know what to do here?

Comment: When you made changes in the registry. According to that date restore on that day. Follow teh instruction given in answer by @Mokubai.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to restore your system to the state it was in before you modified the registry.

You should be able to find a restore point a day or two before the change, select it, follow the prompts and wait.